# NSDateFormatter not working while formatting

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a time string, which is as shown below:

```
2/5/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

and i want to change this in to `MM/dd/yyyy` formate.

i used NSDateFormatter, but i am getting a null value. how can i change this??

Comment: 1000 of dupes here.. you have parse the string to a date (match the format!) and the output date to string with your format

Answer (score 1):

check your code, must be doing something wrong, this is how you receive the right format..

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
```

[Read this document for date formatters.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)